# Error Deleting Files during Uninstall Custom Action (InstallShield)

Tags: file-io, installshield, uninstallation, custom-action

I'm writing a C++ function in a standard dll to delete files in a folder during uninstall. These files were added by the application at some point.

I'm using DeleteFile to delete the files one by one. The DeleteFile is returning an ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED error. The DeleteFile is called from the InstallShiel uninstall as a custom action during After InstallValidate when REMOVE="ALL".

Any ideas why I'm getting ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED? I'm uninstalling as an administrative user.

The InstallShield poject is a Basic MSI Project install. I'm using InstallShield Spring 2012 professional.

The Delete function works correctly when called from a normal test application (Windows Forms Application).  The Dll is a Win32 dll.

Answer (score 1):

What type of files are these and where are they located? If the files are to be considered user data I would not remove them at all.

Use MSI's [**RemoveFile table**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) whenever possible to remove files on install or uninstall. It is way too error prone and time consuming to use custom actions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove file table will work, but not if the .exe calling the DLL is in use.
If this is the case you can place a custom action with the condition `REMOVEALL=TRUE`, then simply kill the process.

You will want to put this earlier in the InstallExecute sequence so that it runs in silent mode.

For example, in VBScript:

```vb
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "taskkill /im exeprocessname.exe", , True
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused because the dll with the function being called is in the folder being deleted.